# Is there a way to use version of dependency declared in Spring Boot BOM

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, maven-bom

I have a Gradle-based project with root `build.gradle` declaring dependency on Spring Boot BOM:

```
ext {
  springBootVersion = '2.6.3'
}

subprojects {
  dependencies {
    implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:$springBootVersion")
  }
}
```

then in a subproject I have dependencies on `liquibase-core` and `liquibase-cdi`:

```
ext {
  liquiBaseVersion = '4.4.3'
}

dependencies {
  runtimeOnly "org.liquibase:liquibase-cdi:$liquiBaseVersion"
  runtimeOnly "org.liquibase:liquibase-core"
}
```

the problem is that the version of `liquibase-core` is automatically picked up from Spring Boot BOM declared in root `build.gradle`, but `liquibase-cdi` is not specified in that BOM, so I have to declare its version explicitly (otherwise `gradle build` fails).

I'd like to use somehow the version of `liquibase-core` specified in Spring Boot BOM for `liquibase-cdi` like this can be done with Maven placeholder `${liquibase.version}` referencing the property specified in `<properties/>` of parent pom.

Is there a way to do the same with Gradle?

Comment: For libraries that `spring-boot-dependencies` manages, we aim to include all of their modules. In other words, `liquibase-cdi` should be managed. I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29676.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
dependencyManagement.importedProperties['spring.version']
```

to get for example the `spring.version` property which is managed via the Dependency Management Plugin.

See https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#accessing-properties for details.

You can also use the programmatic access to the dependency management to find the managed version of Liquibase:

```
def liquibaseVersion = managedVersions['org.liquibase:liquibase-core']
```

See https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#working-with-managed-versions-programmatic-access

Comment: This only works if he uses Spring's Dependency Management plugin. Given the platform declaration, I would assume he doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I voted up, but it's not working in my case with platform declaration